# Confusion with [specialization] and [template-specialization] tags

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two tags on Stack Overflow that are possibly related to the same thing:

- [specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specialization)

  > A powerful feature of C++'s templates is 'template specialization'. This allows alternative implementations to be provided based on certain characteristics of the parameterized type that is being instantiated. Template specialization has two purposes: to allow certain forms of optimization, and to reduce code bloat.
- [template-specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-specialization)

  > Template specialization refers to programmer-generated explicit specialization of templates for specific types.

Is it a way to avoid this ambiguity? Which tag should I prefer to use if there is no such solution?

Comment: From a cursory examination, they appear to refer to the same subject area, and might be good candidates for merging. After which, one can be made into a synonym of the other.

Comment: This post on [synonyms and merging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) says nothing about having to merge before suggesting a synonym. I thought they looked similar at first glance as well but the second one seems terribly generic.

Comment: I suppose that's why there are rep and tag-score criteria for suggesting synonyms, so the people who know the domain can make that judgement. OP seems to meet the criteria for suggesting a synonym.